# Как сделать чтобы анимация повторялась?

Tags: html5-canvas

Нужно, чтобы линии стирались и прорисовывались заново

```js
var w = c.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = c.height = window.innerHeight,
    ctx = c.getContext( '2d' ),
    
    opts = {
     
      len: 50,
      count: 50,
      baseTime: 40,
      addedTime: 10,
      dieChance: .01,
      spawnChance: 1,
      sparkChance: .1,
      sparkDist: 10,
      sparkSize: 2,
      
      color: 'hsl(hue,100%,light%)', // color: 'hsl(hue,100%,light%)',
      baseLight: 50,
      addedLight: 10, // [50-10,50+10]
      shadowToTimePropMult: 6,
      baseLightInputMultiplier: .01,
      addedLightInputMultiplier: .02,
      
      cx: w / 2,
      cy: h / 2,
      repaintAlpha: 1,
      alpha:true, 
      hueChange: .1
    },
    
    tick = 0,
    lines = [],
    dieX = w / 2 / opts.len,
    dieY = h / 2 / opts.len,
    
    baseRad = Math.PI * 2 / 6;
    // ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(1,22,0,1)';
    // fillStyle = 'red';
    // ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );

function loop() {
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame( loop );
  
  ++tick;
  
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255, 0)'.replace( 'alp', opts.repaintAlpha );
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'light';
  
  if( lines.length < opts.count && Math.random() < opts.spawnChance )
    lines.push( new Line );
  
  lines.map( function( line ){ line.step(); } );
}
function Line(){
  
  this.reset();
}
Line.prototype.reset = function(){
  
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.addedX = 0;
  this.addedY = 0;
  
  this.rad = 0;
  
  this.lightInputMultiplier = opts.baseLightInputMultiplier + opts.addedLightInputMultiplier * Math.random();
  
  this.color = opts.color.replace( 'hue', tick * opts.hueChange );
  this.cumulativeTime = 0;
  
  this.beginPhase();
}
Line.prototype.beginPhase = function(){
  
  this.x += this.addedX;
  this.y += this.addedY;
  
  this.time = 0;
  this.targetTime = ( opts.baseTime + opts.addedTime * Math.random() ) |0;
  
  this.rad += baseRad * ( Math.random() < .5 ? 1 : -1 );
  this.addedX = Math.cos( this.rad );
  this.addedY = Math.sin( this.rad );
  
  if( Math.random() < opts.dieChance || this.x > dieX || this.x < -dieX || this.y > dieY || this.y < -dieY )
    this.reset();
}
Line.prototype.step = function(){
  
  ++this.time;
  ++this.cumulativeTime;
  
  if( this.time >= this.targetTime )
    this.beginPhase();
  
  var prop = this.time / this.targetTime,
      wave = Math.sin( prop * Math.PI / 2  ),
      x = this.addedX * wave,
      y = this.addedY * wave;
  
//   ctx.shadowBlur = prop * opts.shadowToTimePropMult;
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.shadowColor = '#8BC641'
//   ctx.fillStyle = ctx.shadowColor = this.color.replace( 'light', opts.baseLight + opts.addedLight * Math.sin( this.cumulativeTime * this.lightInputMultiplier ) );
  ctx.fillRect( opts.cx + ( this.x + x ) * opts.len, opts.cy + ( this.y + y ) * opts.len, 2, 2 );
  

}
loop();
```

```html
    <canvas id='c'></canvas>
```